# Rewrite URL Parameters .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have searched and searched for tutorials on this but mod_rewrite is breaking my brain and I can't get this one figured out. Can anyone shed some light on the following rewrite please?

```
CURRENT: ?fruit=Oranges&vegetable=Carrots
DESIRED: /oranges-vs-carrots/
```

For clarity, I am looking for help with the rewrite conditions needed to achieve the desired URL.

Comment: What do you need? Do you need an explaination of this rewrite or need something to be fixed?

Comment: I'm hoping for an explanation of how to get this rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fruit=(.+)&vegetable=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1-vs-%2/? [R,L]
```

`%1` is the same as `$1` in normal regex but for the last RewriteCond
And `%{QUERY_STRING}` is the "variables" part of your URL.

Comment: Works a charm, thank you. I don't suppose you could add some comments? I follow the regex but %1 and %2 ... not sure how these are set as what appears like 'variables'.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer. `%1` is the same as `$1` but for the last RewriteCond.